# ImageIcon lost after creating a runnable JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, image, embedded-resource, imageicon

[image]

The project runs fine when I click **play** in Eclipse but after I created the **runnable JAR file**, The `ImageIcon` for the button is gone.
The images are stored within the src folder, uder a subfolder images.
I created the image icon as

Icon playIcon = (Icon) new ImageIcon("src/images/play.png");

### Although I am using a relative path, the button does not display images, How do I get the images even in the JAR file?

---

---

#### Update after Nikolay Kuznetsov's answer

I ended up creating a very unstructured monolithic code for screen recorder and now it  is slightly difficult to implement what he said.
I was wondering if there is a way like creating a class or interface that will contain all these resources.

For example:

```
public class embeddedResources {
    public static Icon blackCursor;
    public static Icon whiteCursor;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Then all I have to do is import these statics and in my main `ScreenRecorder` class,

```
this.blackCursor = embeddedResources.blackCorsor;
```

Comment: If your image is inside jar then you probably should read it via `getResourceAsStream(path)` method from `Class` class.

Comment: have you checked whether resources are really embedded? open with zip and check.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov zip does not even detect the jar file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using this method to read image into `BufferedImage` where IconManager is class where it is defined.

```
private static BufferedImage readBufferedImage (String imagePath) {
    try {
        InputStream is = IconManager.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(imagePath);
        BufferedImage bimage = ImageIO.read(is);
        is.close();
        return bimage;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @LittleChild, yes, you can do that. For example, my IconManager manages all resources (images) so I can load/read them at startup and then just get using getters.

Comment: I will have to create an object of type `IconManager` or in my case `embeddedResources` as the very first line of code?

Comment: `IconManager` is just arbitrary name. You can use `EmbeddedResources` or `ResourceManager`. And use capital letter for class names.

Comment: @LittleChild, do you know difference between object and class?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
Try to make you JAR file and add your images to an extern folder.
So you have a folder "Game" in this folder are the folder for your images called "images" or so and your jar file.
If you now edit you folder path to "../images/play.png" it should work.

Comment: That will not allow me to share the JAR file with my friends.