# Java does not load embedded Images

Tags: java, embedded-resource

```
package common;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ResourcesToAccess {
    public static Icon sharedAbstractDownIcon;
    public static Icon sharedAbstractPlayIcon;
    public static Icon sharedAbstractPauseIcon;
    public static Icon sharedAbstractBlackCursor;
    public static Icon sharedAbstractWhiteCursor;
    public ResourcesToAccess(){
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/src/images/blackCursor.png");
        try{
            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(is);
            sharedAbstractBlackCursor = (Icon) new ImageIcon(bi);
            new JFrame().add(new JLabel(sharedAbstractBlackCursor)).setVisible(true);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ResourcesToAccess();
    }
}
```

I am using this code to see whether the `PNG` images can be properly loaded to create JLabels, Icons, etc but I get the error that:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at common.ResourcesToAccess.<init>(ResourcesToAccess.java:21)
    at common.ResourcesToAccess.main(ResourcesToAccess.java:29)
```

Why do I see that error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images/blackCursor.png")
```

it is looking in your classpath so no more `src` directory there

Comment: you might wanna check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023146/imageicon-lost-after-creating-a-runnable-jar-file **easy way out will be appreciated**